# No type information in kSOAP2

Tags: java, android, web-services, soap, ksoap2

I'm trying to access a web service from `Android`. `kSOAP` (I've tried `2.4` and am now using `3.0.0 RC5`) seemed like a good way to do it. I can access the service just fine with

```
SoapObject soapRequest = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(soapRequest);
HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
androidHttpTransport.debug=true;
androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
Log.d("soap", androidHttpTransport.responseDump);
```

but there is no type info.

This is especially bad, because the return type is an array of a type that has several subtypes and only properties of the supertype are in the response, no matter of which type the items in the array are.

How can I get a correctly typed response?

Answer (score 0):

For an array of object response, you can check [here](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/wiki/CodingTipsAndTricks#sending/receiving_array_of_complex_types_or_primitives), almost everything you need is there. 
And [this answer](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/wiki/CodingTipsAndTricks#sending/receiving_array_of_complex_types_or_primitives) is a way to parse complex object from response, which is tested.
Hope this help.